# How to get the nearest point of obstacle to current point of gameobject in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

It is just Simple Image, nevermind of triangle.
Point Pi is my gameobjcet.transform.position, Point Po is obstacle.transform.position.
I want to find Pn.
The circle with radius PoPn is unreachable area by NavMesh.
So I want to set destination Pn instead Po.
Anyway, I just need to find closest point on NavMesh from obstacle like Pn between Pi and Po.
Let me know your solutions.

Thank you.

I had found public functions realated to NavMesh and NavMeshAgent in Unity Documentation. But I failed to find the point Pn Between Pi and Po.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you know

```
Vector3 Pi = transform.position;
Vector3 Po = obstacle.transform.position;
float radius = YOUR_RADIUS;
```

so all you want is just

```
Vector3 Pn = Po + (Pi - Po).normalized * radius;
```

the point that goes the distance of `radius` from `Po` in direction towards `Pi`